# Merge JAR files from Processing on Mac

Tags: java, jar, processing, executable-jar

Hi I know there are tons of articles about how to merge jars, but my problem is a little different.

I want to use a bash script to merge jar files. All my jar (from Processing) are lying in ./lib
Here is what I do:

```sh
mkdir tmp
FILES=lib/*.jar
for T in $FILES; do
  (cd tmp; jar -xf ../$T)
done
jar -cfm combined.jar tmp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  -C tmp .
```

Of course I get a jar File but it's not really acting like it should.

BTW: I make sure that the jar extracted last is the main applications jar.

Comment: How *is* it acting ? How *should* it be acting ?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Or what making sure "the jar extracted last is the main applications jar" means.

Comment: Because each JAR includes it's own Manifest. As all other JAR are just libraries and not executable I need to make sure to use the right Manifest with the right Main Class.

It acts in a way that I doesn't find some of the libraries referenced.

Comment: @John Not finding classes referenced in other jars means something else is going wrong; at worst the broken manifest would try to run the wrong main. Also, if you don't use an `@` reply the person you're responding to may not be notified you've replied.

Comment: I'd use [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) to achieve that. Using native scripts somehow hurts the Java way of coding (even when packaging): "write once, bug, I mean, run everywhere" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This script works fine for me when I grab ALL the required jars from Processing (2.1 on OSX in my case). Here are the contents of my 'lib' folder before running it:

```
MySketch.jar
core.jar
gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar
gluegen-rt.jar
jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar
jogl-all.jar
```

If you use any libraries, you need to include ALL the jars for those as well.

Comment: rednoyz good that it works for you. I haven't jumped to Processing 2.1 yet as the OpenGL doesn't work. But I'll try. I have figured out another way tho.